# repalcing the string value

Tags: c#

lets  say i have an string str="45.6767676";
 **now in output  i need to show as 45.67**
 if the string  as str= "4";
 **then   show the output as  4**
 is there any built in function  to  do this.
 thanks

Comment: Are you sure you don't want "45.68"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
double value = double.Parse(str);
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("##.##"));
```

Answer (score 0):

See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the string contains a decimal. If it does, then make use of the options provided in the link posted by Jouke. If it does not, then don't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
Console.WriteLine(Double.Parse("4.676767").ToString("0.##"));
```